# Same object saved to NSUserDefaults over and over again when the NSMutableDictionary is different

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, dictionary, nsuserdefaults

It's driving me crazy, I did a log and I see the objects are different, but when I get then back from `NSUserDefaults`, all of the objects are the same.
My code:

```
- (void)breakTrapsToSave:(NSDictionary*)trapsDict firstTimeUpdate:(Boolean)firstTimeUpdate
{
    // If traps already save
    // we will get them from NSUserDefaults
    // and then update them
    if (!firstTimeUpdate)
    {
        allTraps = [self.sharedPrefs objectForKey:@"arrayOfAllTraps"];
    }

    // JSON Parsing
    tempA = trapsDict[@"Envelope"];
    tempB = tempA[@"Body"];
    tempC = tempB[@"getTrapsResponse"];
    tempD = tempC[@"getTrapsResult"];
    tempE = tempD[@"TRAPS"];

    self.lastUpdate = tempE[@"lastUpdate"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.lastUpdate forKey:@"last_update"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    NSLog(@"Traps latest updated at: %@", self.lastUpdate);

    tempF = tempE[@"TRAP"];

    if (tempF.count <= 0)
    {
        newTrapsUpdates = false;
        NSLog(@"NO NEW TRAPS!");
    }
    else
    {
        newTrapsUpdates = true;
        NSLog(@"NEW TRAPS FOUND");

        [tempF enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            tempA = tempF[idx];
            NSString *finalResult;
            NSString *key;
            NSMutableDictionary *singleTrap = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

            for (int i=0; i < node.count; i++)
            {
                finalResult = tempA[node[i]];
                key = node[i];

                if ([finalResult length] <= 0)
                {
                    finalResult = @"0";
                }
                singleTrap[key] = finalResult;
            }

            if (allTraps.count <= 0)
            {
                allTraps = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:singleTrap, nil];
            }
            else
            {
                [allTraps addObject:singleTrap];
            }
            counter = idx;
        }];

        allTraps = [[IDANNetroads sharedInstance] removeDuplicatedFromArray:allTraps];

        // Save all traps
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:allTraps forKey:@"arrayOfAllTraps"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        NSLog(@"Total Traps: %d", allTraps.count);
        NSLog(@"Total New Traps: %d", counter);
    }
}
```

I did a log and I see `allTraps[idx] = singleTrap;` is different as it should be, but when I print the log for `NSLog(@"allTraps: %@", allTraps);` I see all of the objects are the last object.

**EDIT:**

Eventually, I replaced the singleTrap allocation and now it's inside the enumeration block:

```
NSMutableDictionary *singleTrap = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

And I added this code:

```
if (allTraps.count <= 0)
            {
                allTraps = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:singleTrap, nil];
            }
            else
            {
                [allTraps addObject:singleTrap];
            }
```

So, the final code is edited.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever `singleTrap` is, you're repeatedly mutating it and storing another reference to the same object in your `allTraps` array. You need to create (instantiate) a new item for each entry you want in your `allTraps` list.

---

It looks like `singleTrap` is an array of strings, so try:

```
allTraps[idx] = [singleTrap copy];
```